# tmux use mouse only to resize panes

Tags: tmux

In new versions of tmux, I know that I can use `set -g mouse on` to enable mouse support in order to be able to resize panes with the mouse.

But it also enable a feature that I do not want which is using copy mode when I select text in the terminal. In that way I am no more able to copy text in the system clipboard in order to paste it outside of tmux.

My question is: is there a way to enable resizing panes with the mouse, which very handy, without having to enable mouse support for other things?

Answer (score 1):

Because there in no answer, I will try to answer myself:

Apparently there is no way to do this, since when a mouse event is intercepted by tmux, it cannot be forwarded to the system. I say this but it is pure deduction, I have no knowledge about that.

As an alternative, there is a way to prevent tmux to intercept the mouse, by holding a key like "fn" on Mac OS.